# React Webpack in Production Error #105

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm kind of desperate here.

I'm working on a React application and use webpack to compile my bundle.js.
The problem is when i try to compile it for "production" i end up with a really nasty error :

"Minified React error #105; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=105&args[]=HardwareKeyboardArrowDown for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings."

Followed by a bunch of 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$qw6tjofxg1o' of null"

When i set my node.env to developement ('NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('developement') ), it's working fine.

The link in the error says : "A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object" but i don't have any problem in dev mode, so i don't think its coming from my code and i can't find where i should look to solve this problem since dev mode doesn't tell anything more to me...

Here are my webpack config & package.json :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const TransferWebpackPlugin = require('transfer-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: [
    './src/app/app.js'
  ],
  // Render source-map file for final build
  devtool: 'source-map',
  debug: true,
  // output config
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public/'
  },

  plugins: [
    // Define production build to allow React to strip out unnecessary checks
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),

    // Minify the bundle
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        // suppresses warnings, usually from module minification
        warnings: false,
      },
    }),
    // Allows error warnings but does not stop compiling.
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    // Transfer Files

  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // All .js files
        loaders: ['babel-loader'], // react-hot is like browser sync and babel loads jsx and es6-7
        exclude: [nodeModulesPath],
      },
       {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        include: /flexboxgrid/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader",
      },
      { test: /\.scss?$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles') },
      { test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'}
    ],

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.json']
  }
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

---

```
{
  "name": "material-ui-example-webpack",
  "version": "0.16.0",
  "description": "Sample project that uses Material-UI",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/callemall/material-ui.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack-dev-server.config.js --host $IP --port $PORT  --hot --progress --inline --colors",
    "clean-public": "npm run remove-public && mkdir public",
    "remove-public": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./public",
    "build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install && npm-run-all clean-public build:html",
    "heroku-postbuild": "babel-node tools/build.js",
    "prod-start": "babel-node tools/publicServer.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "npm-run-all": "1.8.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.2",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel-cli": "6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "cheerio": "^0.20.0",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "lint": "^1.1.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.17.1",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "1.8.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-component-queries": "^2.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-fittext": "https://github.com/gianu/react-fittext",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^1.0.2",
    "react-html-parser": "^1.0.3",
    "react-masonry-component": "^5.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-responsive": "^1.2.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react-sizeme": "^2.3.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.6.3",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "rimraf": "2.5.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

buildHtml script :

```
import fs from 'fs';  
import cheerio from 'cheerio';  
import colors from 'colors';

/*eslint-disable no-console */
console.log("buildHTML.js start");
fs.readFile('src/index.html', 'utf8', (err, markup) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  const $ = cheerio.load(markup);
  $('head').prepend('');

  fs.writeFile('public/index.html', $.html(), 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('index.html written to /public'.green);
  });
});
```

And then build.js

```
/*eslint-disable no-console */
import webpack from 'webpack';  
import webpackConfig from '../webpack-production.config';  
import colors from 'colors';
import ncp from 'ncp';

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'; 
console.log("build.js start");
//Static files to import in /public (images/css)
var source = [["src/images","public/images"],["src/css","public/css"]];

function copyStaticFiles(path){
    ncp(path[0], path[1], function (err) {
  if (err) {
     return console.error(err);
  }})
}

console.log('Generating minified bundle for production via Webpack...'.blue);

webpack(webpackConfig).run((err, stats) => {  

  if (err) { // so a fatal error occurred. Stop here.
    console.log(err.bold.red);
    return 1;
  }

  const jsonStats = stats.toJson();

  if (jsonStats.hasErrors) {
    return jsonStats.errors.map(error => console.log(error.red));
  }

  if (jsonStats.hasWarnings) {
    console.log('Webpack generated the following warnings: '.bold.yellow);
    jsonStats.warnings.map(warning => console.log(warning.yellow));
  }

  console.log(`Webpack stats: ${stats}`);

  source.forEach(copyStaticFiles);

  console.log('Your app has been compiled in production mode and written to /public.'.green);

  return 0;
});
```

I don't even know where to start and i can't find any documentation about this kind of errors.

I can provide more informations if needed. 
Thanks for reading me

Comment: can you post the jsx of `HardwareKeyboardArrowDown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i dont have a object with a HardwareKeyboardArrowDown so i went looking in my dependencies and i found that it came from the matérial-ui dependency.

I forced the version 17.4 in my package.json and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

The message gave you the name of the function (component) that returns the invalid object. `HardwareKeyboardArrowDown`.
So you should look at the `return` of its `render` function and make sure you return a valid React element (or null)
That means no `undefined`, `array` etc..